# Review my Prim's algorithm implemented in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, prims-algorithm

## Why my implementation is slow for large input?

As you can see below my code works for given input but as I increase the size of input to 10,000 lines of matrix, it runs for days.

I have tried profiling my program for smaller inputs and there is nothing serious memory consumption. I am constantly reading from file so that could be the issue but **iotop** shows no IO read/write at all.

Input

```
 0    31    24    33    26
31     0    32    38    33
26    32     0    29    23
33    38    29     0    31
26    33    23    31     0
```

Code

```
import sys
import linecache


DEBUG = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    line = linecache.getline(sys.argv[1], 1)
    line = line.replace("  ", " ").strip().split()
    neighbours = list([int(_) for _ in line])
    vertices_found = set(range(len(neighbours)))
    if DEBUG:
        print("Initial Vertices: " + str(vertices_found))

    vertices_visited = set()
    vertices_visited.add(0) # start vertex
    edge_weight = 0

    while vertices_found != vertices_visited:
        lowest_v = None
        lowest_col = None
        lowest_nn = 0

        # set lowest_nn to max possible value
        # this step is redundant but useful
        # we can avoid this by setting lowest_nn to some random big value
        for v in vertices_visited:
            # get neighbours from file
            line = linecache.getline(sys.argv[1], v+1)
            line = line.replace("  ", " ").strip().split()
            neighbours = list([int(_) for _ in line])

            for nn in neighbours:
                if nn >= lowest_nn:
                    lowest_nn = nn + 1

        for v in vertices_visited:
            # get neighbours from file
            line = linecache.getline(sys.argv[1], v+1)
            line = line.replace("  ", " ").strip().split()
            neighbours = list(map(int, line))

            for col, nn in enumerate(neighbours):
                if nn > 0 and nn <= lowest_nn and col not in vertices_visited:
                    lowest_v = v
                    lowest_col = col
                    lowest_nn = nn

        if lowest_col is not None:
            vertices_visited.add(lowest_col)
            edge_weight += lowest_nn
            if DEBUG:
                print("Visited Vertices: " + str(vertices_visited))

    print("Minimum Spanning Tree Weight: %d" % edge_weight)
```

How to run it?

Save code in code.py and save input in input.txt then run following command.

```
python code.py input.txt 1
```

Comment: You're repeating tons and tons of computation and making no apparent effort to use efficient data representations.

Comment: If you are talking about finding max lowest_nn is a repetition then I have tried setting lowest_nn to 9999999 and removing that piece of code. It'd be great if you can point me to repeated code.

Comment: On every iteration of the outer loop, you go through every single edge connected to a node in the tree. There are far more efficient ways to find the next edge.

Comment: Which efficient way is mostly used for finding next edge?

Comment: Keep track of the best edge for reaching each vertex instead of going over all of them, use a heap, etc. Google will give you plenty of results for how to implement this.

Comment: If I use heap data structure, assume priority queue then I have to read whole file and store it in priority queue right? Isn't it same as storing whole input in lists? Priority Queue will solve access problem even lists will solve access problem by giving fast access to items but I can't afford to do that. It has to read 1 line at a time from the file.

Comment: "then I have to read whole file and store it in priority queue" - no, you just need to track the frontier. "I can't afford to do that. It has to read 1 line at a time from the file." - do it right, and at worst, it'll be a constant factor more memory-intensive than what you're doing now.

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you already *are* reading the entire file into memory, because the I/O activity you're seeing sounds like the whole file is getting cached.

Comment: Nope I am not reading the whole file in memory. The memory consumption is less than 1% with all input so if IO activity is 0 and memory is very minimum then where it is? I think it's IO but IOTOP can't read this IO activity for some reason.

Comment: what do mean by "frontier"? in "you just need to track the frontier"